# How to extract name from a button (jQuery navigation)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, dom, web-scraping

A part of source code on a specific site looks like this:

```
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .

                       <div class="list-group-item">
        <strong>item 1</strong>
        description
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove"
           data-id="5e98a2dc5e0aye57597b181b">
            Unsubscribe
        </a>
    </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
        <strong>item 2</strong>
        description
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove"
           data-id="5e58ac128edaey3f2935d94b">
            Unsubscribe
        </a>
    </div>
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
```

How do I grab each `data-id` value?

I tried

```
      $('.list-group-item').each(function(){
        var text = ($(this).text());
        console.log(text);
      });
```

But it returns `item 1(2)`, `description` and `Unsubscribe` text.

I also tried

```
      $('.btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove').each(function(){
        var text2 = ($(this).text());
        console.log(text2);
      });
```

But this doesn't work at all.
What command should I use to grab data-id values successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn.btn-default.btn-xs.pull-right.listing-sub-remove").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).data("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class="list-group-item">
       <strong>item 1</strong>
       description
       <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove" data-id="5e98a2dc5e0aye57597b181b">
         Unsubscribe
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="list-group-item">
       <strong>item 2</strong>
       description
       <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove" data-id="5e58ac128edaey3f2935d94b">
         Unsubscribe
       </a>
     </div>
```

Comment: thank you but how do I grab data exactly from `btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove`? There are also several `class="btn btn-footer"` on the page which messes up the results

Comment: @narra_kk I've just adjusted my answer to this requirement :)

Comment: So I had to replace all spaces with dots. Much appreciated. Maybe you can also tell me where I can read some guides which would boost my knowledge in this topic?

Comment: @narra_kk Unfortunately not. I've never read a guide myself and learned all what I've learned in production. But I guess you can find online tutorials easily using Google. Maybe a good start is https://learn.jquery.com/ ?

Comment: @narra_kk Btw as you might be interested in this - instead of $(this).data("id") I could have written $(this).attr("data-id") and get the same result. If you read out a data-attribute using data() you omit the "data-" part of the attribute name, therefore it's just data("id").

Comment: @narra_kk Regarding your selector issue, to learn more you should simply search google for "MDN, css selectors".  jQuery selectors conform to match css selectors, with some additional extras detailed in the https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
// We gather ALL elements with '.list-group-item' class
var elements = $(".list-group-item");
  // We iterate over each element in the array of elements
  $.each(elements, function(index, element) {
  // We create a variable that takes the child link anchor [a tag], and grabs the data-id attribute from it
  var dataId = $(element).find("a")[0].dataset.id;
  // If the variable is not undefined, it will console log the result
  if (dataId) { console.log(dataId); };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item">
  <strong>item 1</strong> description
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove" data-id="5e98a2dc5e0aye57597b181b">
            Unsubscribe
        </a>
</div>
<div class="list-group-item">
  <strong>item 2</strong> description
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove" data-id="5e58ac128edaey3f2935d94b">
            Unsubscribe
        </a>
</div>
.
```

Comment: As I understand this `find("a")` finds this string: `<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right listing-sub-remove" data-id="5e58ac128edaey3f2935d94b">
            Unsubscribe
        </a>` How does `dataset.id` work if there is no `dataset` word in a string?

Comment: I can amend to add a conditional check very easily.

Comment: I'll add comments to make it more clear. Apologies.

Comment: It seemed when I originally looked at it, that you wanted to target the list-group-item instead of just the link itself. That's why I went the way I did. Target the anchor tag directly is a more direct approach that seems to fit your use case.